# how to call a text file data in email body by using python script

Tags: python

I am new in Python. I have the below script to send email from `isilon` cluster.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

#
# Helper script to send mail using the Isilon libraries
#

import sys
from optparse import OptionParser
import socket
from isi.app.lib.emailer import Emailer, EmailAttachmentFromFile

# Emailer.send_email(to_addresses(list), message(string), from_address=None(string),  subject=None(string),
#                    attachments=None(list), headers=None(list), charset="us-ascii"(string))

def main():
    usage = '%prog: [-f sender] -t recipient [ -t recipient ... ] [-s subject] [-b body] [-a attachment]'
    argparser = OptionParser(usage = usage, description = 'Send email from a cluser node')
    argparser.add_option('-f', '--from', '--sender', dest='sender',
    help="email sender (From:)")
    argparser.add_option('-t', '--to', '--recipients', dest='recipients',
    action = 'append', help="email recipient (To:)")
    argparser.add_option('-s', '--subject', dest='subject',
    help="email subject (Subject:)")
    argparser.add_option('-b', '--body', dest='body',
    help="email body (default stdin)")
    argparser.add_option('-a', '--attachment', '--file', dest='attfiles',
    action = 'append', help="attachment filename")
    (options, args) = argparser.parse_args()
    if options.sender is None:
        fqdn = socket.getfqdn()
        sender = "root@%s" % fqdn
    else:
       sender = options.sender  
    if options.recipients is None:
        argparser.error("Unable to send mail without at least one recipient");
        sys.exit(1);
    else:
        recipients = options.recipients
    if options.subject is None:
        subject = 'No subject specified'
    else:
        subject = options.subject
    if options.body is None:
        lines = sys.stdin.readlines()
        body = ''.join(lines)
    else:
        body = options.body
    if options.attfiles is None:
        atts = None
    else:
        atts = []
    for attfile in options.attfiles:
        att = EmailAttachmentFromFile(attfile)
        atts.append(att)
    try:
        Emailer.send_email(recipients, body, sender, subject, attachments = atts)
    except:
        print "Error sending email."
        sys.exit(1)

    sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

By using the below command i can able to send the email. Test email is successful.

```
python sendml.py -f xxxx@xxxx.xx -t xxxxxxxx@xxxx.xxx -s "test0" -b "test1"
```

But now i have to display a content of file in email body. Not as an attachment, the content should be displayed in email body.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple and tricky ;) just do this:

```
python sendml.py -f xxxx@xxxx.xx -t xxxxxxxx@xxxx.xxx -s "test0" -b "`cat body.txt`"
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. I tried the same but i am getting the output as `cat body.txt`.. The content of the text is not coming in body of email.